# How to use wildcard search in apache solr search module?

Tags: 7, search

I am working on apachesolr search module.

I want to implement wildcard search I have used `hook_apachesolr_query_prepare()` function to modify `apachesolr query` but it is not working can any one give me solution.
I have implemented code like this.

I have taken reference from here : https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr/issues/1539284

```
function custommodule_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface &$query, &$caller) {

  $search = '';
  $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $query->getParam('q')); 

  foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $search .= '*' . strtolower($keyword) . '* ';    
  }

  $query->addParam('defType', 'edismax');  
  $query->replaceParam('q', $search);  

}
```

**ENV**: Drupal `7.60` | Solr `3.X`

Comment: which drupal version you work with, and wich solr version please?

Comment: drupal 7.60, solr 3.x

Comment: if you just copied the `solrconfig.xml` from `3.X` folder, add `<requestHandler name="drupal" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
` mention in the issue page,  because it's not added by default in the config example come with `search_api_solr` module.